# how to setup chrome-extension cookie permission

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a manifest

```
{
  "name": "Question Share",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Build an awesome world!",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com"
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

with cookies permission. But, when I load unpacked extension in Chrome

Detail tab always show "This extension requires no special permissions"

I'm flowing document: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/

how to call: chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores

please help!

Comment: `"*://*.google.com"` should be `"*://*.google.com/"`

Comment: I have to change it to
```
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com/"
  ],
```
but, in extension detail, show 
```
Permissions
- Display notifications
```

don't show cookies

Comment: It's correct. Chrome doesn't show every single item from `permissions`.